# Differential Equation Involving Multiplication of Infinite Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation $y'' + e^x y = 0$, where $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$. In my class, we are told to use the substitution $y = \sum_{j=0} ^{\infty} a_{j}x^{j}$. However, when it comes to the $e^x y$ term, my professor said to convert $e^x$ to the power series for it, i.e. $\sum_{j=0} ^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}$ and multiply this series with the series for $y$. This troubles me because, in general, you cannot multiply infinite series this way. Please advise; can we just treat $e^x$ as a constant and multiply it into the series for $y$?

Sincerely,
One very confused and frustrated ginger kitty

Comment: You can't treat $e^x$ as constant because, well, it's not constant.

Comment: You could also try to set $y$ as a series in powers of the exponential function, $y=\sum b_ke^{kx/m}$ with $m=1,2,...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what your professor said, you need to write
$$y = \sum_{j=0} ^{\infty} a_{j}\,x^{j} \qquad \text{and} \qquad e^x=\sum_{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ Because of the conditions, you must have $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$.

So, the equation write

$$\sum_{j=0} ^{\infty} j(j-1)a_{j}\,x^{j-2}+\left(\sum_{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \right)\left(\sum_{j=0} ^{\infty} a_{j}\,x^{j}\right)=0$$ and you need to identify the $a_j$'s.

If you start expanding an grouping for the first terms, you should get something like
$$(2 a_2+1)+(6 a_3+1) x+\left(a_2+12 a_4+\frac{1}{2}\right)
   x^2+\left(a_2+a_3+20 a_5+\frac{1}{6}\right)
   x^3+\left(\frac{a_2}{2}+a_3+a_4+30 a_6+\frac{1}{24}\right)
   x^4+\cdots=0$$ Now, just write that each coefficient is equal to $0$. This would give $a_2=-\frac 12$, $a_3=-\frac 16$ and so on.

Comment: The first sum should be $x^{j-2}$

Comment: @Dylan. Ooops ! Sorry for the typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help; I appreciate it. This makes sense in how you set it up without exactly trying to "multiply two infinite series", but rather focusing on what the terms look like when you expand it a bit.